# Replace all middle characters in a string c++

Tags: c++, string, replace, find

I know I have asked a question similar to this in the not to distant past and I am sorry for asking a similar one but I can work out how do do this one thing with my code. I want to leave the first and last character in a string as they are and replace all the characters in the centre.

```
// finds all banned words
size_t pos = textWords[i].find(bannedWords[j]); 

// checks through the vector to find all words in the banned list
if (string::npos != pos) 
{
    // replaces the middle character with a *
    textWords[i].replace(pos + 1 , 1 , 1 , '*'); 
}
```

This is the code that i am using it works but it only works with three lettered words and i want it to work with any length of word.

Again I am sorry for asking a similar question to one I asked before but I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation on `std::string::replace` you'll see that the call you're using

```
textWords[i].replace(pos + 1 , 1 , 1 , '*');
```

Means "replace 1 character starting at position pos+1 with one '*' character", if you want to change all but the first and last letter you should use

```
textWords[i].replace(pos + 1 , bannedWords[j].size()-2 , bannedWords[j].size()-2 , '*');
```

That is, change `bannedWords[j].size()-2` characters in `textWords[i]` for `bannedWords[j].size()-2` '*' characters.

Answer (score 4):

Example using [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) (uses the first of 5th variation on the linked page):

```
std::string s = "a-test-string";
s.replace(1, s.length() - 2, s.length() -2, '*');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the overload of [`std::string::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) that takes a single character and duplicates it a specified number of times.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string s( "expletive" );

  s.replace( 1, s.size() - 2, s.size() - 2, '*' );
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
e*******e
```